# Preventing right-floated slider from moving further right when left-floated slider label displays double digit value

Tags: html, css

Need to place two sliders side-by-side as volume controls. Each has a label which displays volume from 1 to 100. Used float right, float left. When the left slider's volume label goes from single to double digits, this moves the right slider and its label to the right. Have tried using clear without success. Must be doing something wrong.

Is there a way to prevent the right slider and its label from moving further right when the left slider is moved and produces a double digit value (10+) in its label?

Example code below is for 2 side-by-side sliders to illustrate the problem. The actual project has 10 left side and 10 right side volume sliders (plus on/off buttons and labels for each audio element).

```js
var S1 = new Audio('audio/sound1.mp3');
var S2 = new Audio('audio/sound2.mp3');
function setVol1(){
input = document.getElementById('volumeOne');    
element = document.getElementById("volumeVal");
element.innerHTML = input.value;
}
function setVol2(){
input2 = document.getElementById('volumeTwo');
element2 = document.getElementById("volumeVal2");
element2.innerHTML = input2.value;
}
```

```css
<style>
input.slider {
  width: 300px;
}
label {
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 110px;
}
.left-side{
}
.right-side{
} 
</style>
```

```html
<div class= "left-side;" style="float:left;" >  
<div>
<input id=volumeOne type=range min=0 max=100 value=0 step=1 oninput="setVol1()">
<span id="volumeVal">0</span><br>
</div>
</div>
<div class= "right-side;" >  
<div style="float:right;">
</div>
<div>
<input id=volumeTwo type=range min=0 max=100 value=0 step=1 oninput="setVol2()">
<span id="volumeVal2">0</span><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the text to overlap the other slider?

Comment: No. Each slider and volume label needs to be separate-no text overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display: inline-block;` to the `<span>` so that it respects dimensions like width, then you can give it a `min-width`:

```js
function setVol(input) {
  input.nextElementSibling.innerText = input.value;
}
```

```css
input.slider {
  width: 300px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 2em;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-side;" style="float:left;">
  <div>
    <input id=volumeOne type=range min=0 max=100 value=0 step=1 oninput="setVol(this)">
    <span id="volumeVal">0</span><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-side;">
  <div style="float:right;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id=volumeTwo type=range min=0 max=100 value=0 step=1 oninput="setVol(this)">
    <span id="volumeVal2">0</span><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, T J. I'll try it, report back.

Comment: Works until I add in my more complex controls (on/off button and its label("on" or "off"). Adding these (slider, label, plus button, label) doesn't work. If I add inline-block and min-width to button label, works again, but volume label is now moved to next line (then all controls-10 plus 10 side-by-side no longer fit height on project screen. Will keep experimenting. Looks like adding inline -block to button label is needed to prevent shifting to right, but this also moves volume label to next line. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: I think the right side 10 controls floating right may cause the volume label to get pushed to a new, next line? Not sure how to prevent this, if this is the problem. If I remove float right for these controls, they position below the first 10 (left side) controls, way off the bottom of the web page.

Comment: OK, I figured out a work-around: add my volume label to first line (button, its label and now, volume label), with some labels text abbreviating to fit on one line.

Comment: @saratogacoach you can also use things like `:last-child{ ... }` selector to reset/clear some styles at the end of a list

Comment: Will read up on :last-child, see if I can apply it. But new design (as mentioned in previous comment) is clean, saves space without sacrificing clarity, seems to work OK. Thank you again for this solution.